# Integration $\int_0^1 \cos \left(\sqrt{c+ b x+x^2}\right) \, dx$

Tags: integration

How to integrate $\int_0^1 \cos \left(\sqrt{c+b x+x^2}\right) \, dx$? $b$ and $c$ can be any value (except both equal to zero) as long as the integration can be done.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe it has a closed form?

Comment: At first $b^2<4c$ for  quantity under radical sign to be positive. Doubt it can be solved analytically. What are your attempts?

Comment: @anon I don't, and that's part of the reason I'm asking.

Comment: @Narasimham I only tried to get the form close to what Yves gives below.

Comment: But dont care for getting to a solution later ?

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 3):

As the integrand has two degrees of freedom, the integration bounds are virtually immaterial and the definite integral isn't simpler than the indefinite one.

And the indefinite one doesn't have a closed-form expression. By a linear change of variable, you can reduce to
$$\int \cos\left(\sqrt{t^2+1}\right)\,dt$$ then $$\int \cos(\cosh u)\cosh u\,du$$
or 
$$\int\frac{u\cos(u)}{\sqrt{u^2-1}}\,du$$
but this leads you nowhere.